# Regular Expression Text Selection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I'm working on a website where I have some text which I am using the RedCloth gem to markdown. basically I need to intercept some text before it gets to the gem, and parse the text with a colour code syntax gem. My regex is very poor (and I don't know if I can do this.) I need to select chucks of text and parse them before RedCloth gets ahold of it.

example text

I need to select (in ruby) the chucks of text that start with ##code(language) and end with #code, I also need to know what is inside of the bracket at the start tag ##code(in-here)

```
other text.....

##code(ruby)

puts "Hello World"

##code

more text.......


##code(c++)

#include <string>
#include "logger.h"

##code

etc...
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Phil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
/##code\((\S+)\)(.+?)##code/m
```

That'll match any non-space character, so as long as your (language) stuff doesn't have spaces, you'll be good to go.

Comment: /##code\\((\S+)\\)(.+)##code/m He needs to match what's inside the (language) pattern as well.

Comment: Updated per suggestions. Thanks guys.

Comment: is it possible to stop it removing slashes?
>> "##code(ruby) \\\\ ##code".sub(/##code\\((\S+)\\)(.+?)##code/m, "\\\\")
=> "\\"

not sure why the back slashes are being removed

Comment: Might want to ask a new question about that one